# How can I get a value from entity as String

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to get a value from an entity with the field name as String?

For example:

```
public class User{
    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;
}
```

And I have the String lastname.

How can I get the lastname?

repo.findby...?

Thanks

Comment: Try `repo.findByLastname(String lastName)`

Comment: I have the name of the column as String. I don't want to search by lastname, but obtain the lastname value of this object User. I want to do User user = ...; The user.get...

Comment: Try `@Query` , example @Query(select u.lastName from User u) String getLastName();

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366355/how-to-retrieve-specific-column-from-the-table-jpa-or-crudrepository-i-want/48367844#48367844

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I'm not clear. The string lastname is dynamic. It can be "lastname", but also "firstname", or anythig else (one attribute of the entity)

Comment: That is not possible…You cannot have a dynamic declarative method

Comment: @anubis, You need to create query manually if your field are dynamic and use `EntityManager` to fire query . But it is not recommend , if your dynamic field comes from user input then it is susceptible to SQL injection

Comment: You mean the property to return is selected dynamically? Why not just return the entity from the query, and have your own mechanism to decide which method on the 'user' instance based on the selection required? You can also query using criteria queries (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries which focuses on returning entities when you only want the partial data, but is a good start) to dynamically and safely build queries, returning String parameter values